# race condition in python methods

Tags: python

I have 2 methods I am calling in a loop one after another

main.py (value is an object)

```
    for value in valueList:               
     value.A()
     value.B()
```

Object.py(the objects definition)

```
    def A(self):
      self.quantity = 10

    def B(self):
      self.quantity = self.quantity + 1
```

in the function B() im getting a attribute error that quantity is not found and the program is racing ahead to B() instead of finishing executing A() first

how do I make sure B() is executed only after A() finishes without calling B() from A()

I am providing the complete code here of both the methods here:

```
              def getYesterdayPosition(self,Pos,csvInstruments):
                 for data in csvInstruments:
                   if data['segment'] == "NFO-FUT":
                     if data['tradingsymbol'] == self.derivative:                   
                        for entry in Pos:
                          if self.derivative == entry['tradingsymbol']:
                            quantity = int(entry['quantity'])
                            self.yesterdays_position = quantity/data['lot_size']                    


               def getPositionDiff(self):
                  if self.yesterdays_position == self.indices:
                     self.trade = 0.0
                  elif self.yesterdays_position > self.indices:
                     self.trade = -(self.yesterdays_position - self.indices)
                  elif self.yesterdays_position < self.indices:
                     self.trade = self.yesterdays_position - self.indices
```

the error is coming in getPositionDiff() where it says it cant find yesterdays_position

main.py 
this is how they are called

```
              for value in orderList:
               value.getYesterdayPosition(jsonPositions['net'],csvInstruments)
               value.getPositionDiff()
```

Comment: ??? `def A()` => `def A(self)`. your code isn't correct, and there isn't any race anywhere... [mcve] please.

Comment: It is racing ahead even though it shouldn't I dont know why

Comment: Can't really happen, must be a different problem. You absolutely need to provide a complete example.

Comment: is that the whole object.py module? if it is, then you need to embed those functions inside a class, and make sure the elements of valueList are instances of said class

Comment: they are in a class and the objects in valueList are instances of that class

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your code is doing. But problem is with getYesterdayPosition method

Inside getYesterdayPosition you have so many if conditions. Any of them is getting failed ,and self.yesterdays_position is not getting declared.

better apply else condition and set some value for False cases.